# Discord bot get number of users in all channels

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im not good with javascript but i have been trying to get count number of users in all voice channels.
For example: if 2 users in 'voice channel 1' and 1 user in 'voice channel 2' I want to print number 3 in console which is all users in voice channels.

```
var Count;
for(Count in bot.users.array()){
   var User = bot.users.array()[Count];
   console.log(User.username);
}
```

This code print all members(online/offline) name in console, But i don't know how to get number of only users in voice channels.

Comment: Is this for a command (or inside a message event)?

Comment: @slothiful Inside bot.on('voiceStateUpdate' , Get updates of count after users join\leave, i already have the code just want to count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter ([`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter)) all the channels in the guild ([`Guild.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels)) to retrieve a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of only voice channels. Then, you can iterate through each channel and add the number of members connected to it to the count.

```js
// Assuming 'newMember' is the second parameter of the event.
const voiceChannels = newMember.guild.channels.filter(c => c.type === 'voice');
let count = 0;

for (const [id, voiceChannel] of voiceChannels) count += voiceChannel.members.size;

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But i got error "ReferenceError: newMember is not defined", i'm sorry i know this is easy but i have no idea about javascript, how can i define this?

Comment: It should be defined as the second parameter in your event. What's the whole line look like for `bot.on('voiceStateUpdate' ...`?

Comment: Thank you it worked like charm, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use this inside an event but use in an embed,message etc; here is my solution. I used @slothiful 's solution but made a bit change.

```
// I used my "message" property. You can change it with yours.
const voiceChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'voice');
let count = 0;

for (const [id, voiceChannel] of voiceChannels) count += voiceChannel.members.size;

message.channel.send(count);
```